# Makefile : Exclude a dependency from $^

Tags: c, makefile, yacc, lex

I'm making a compiler with Lex and Yacc. To compile my `main`, I need yacc to be ran first so the file `y.tab.h` exists. However, I do not want that file to be included in the `$^` variable when compiling said `main`, because the compiler doesn't like getting `.h` files as input.

Is there a way to make that rule/recipe depend on `y.tab.h`, but exclude it from `$^` ?

If not, (meaning, if this question is an XY problem), is there a better way to structure this Makefile to achieve that goal ?

Here is my makefile :

```
targets := ccpy

################################### Options ####################################

cc            := gcc
cFlags        := -c -O3
cFlagsLenient := $(cFlags) -w
cFlagsHard    := $(cFlags) -Wall -pedantic
cFlagsDebug   := -c -W -Wall -pedantic -g -Og
ldFlags       := -lm -ly -ll
ldFlagsDebug  := -g $(ldFlags)

################################### Folders ####################################

binDir   := ./bin
debugDir := ./debug
objDir   := ./obj
srcDir   := ./src
testDir  := ./test

################################ File categories ###############################

mains    := $(targets:%=$(objDir)/%.o)

srcL     := $(wildcard $(srcDir)/*.l)
srcY     := $(wildcard $(srcDir)/*.y)

outL     := $(srcL:$(srcDir)/%.l=$(srcDir)/%.c)
outY     := $(srcY:$(srcDir)/%.y=$(srcDir)/%.c)

objL     := $(outL:$(srcDir)/%.c=$(objDir)/%.o)
objY     := $(outY:$(srcDir)/%.c=$(objDir)/%.o)
cleanY   := $(outY) $(srcY:$(srcDir)/%.y=$(srcDir)/%.h) $(srcDir)/y.output $(srcdir)/y.gv

srcC     := $(filter-out $(outL) $(outY), $(wildcard $(srcDir)/*.c))
objC     := $(srcC:$(srcDir)/%.c=$(objDir)/%.o)

obj      := $(objC) $(objL) $(objY)
objDebug := $(obj:$(objDir)/%.o=$(debugDir)/%.do)

srcTest  := $(wildcard $(testDir)/*.c)
tests    := $(srcTest:$(testDir)/%.c=$(binDir)/%)

#################################### Recipes ###################################

# Basic
all  : $(targets)
again : clean all
debug: $(targets:%=%.db)
test : $(tests)
objects: $(obj)

# Check Variables
info: 
    $(info mains    : $(mains))
    $(info srcC     : $(srcC))
    $(info objC     : $(objC))
    $(info srcL     : $(srcL))
    $(info outL     : $(outL))
    $(info objL     : $(objL))
    $(info srcY     : $(srcY))
    $(info outY     : $(outY))
    $(info objY     : $(objY))
    $(info obj      : $(obj))
    $(info objDebug : $(objDebug))
    $(info srcTest  : $(srcTest))
    $(info tests    : $(tests))

# Final Executables
$(targets): % : $(objDir)/%.o $(obj)
    $(cc) -o $@ $^ $(ldFlags)

# Objects directly compiled from C
$(objC): $(objDir)/%.o : $(srcDir)/%.c
    $(cc) $(cFlagsHard) $^ -o $@

# Objects made by Lex and Yacc
$(objL) $(objY): $(objDir)/%.o : $(srcDir)/%.c
    $(cc) $(cFlagsLenient) $^ -o $@

# Files made by Lex
$(outL): $(srcDir)/%.c : $(srcDir)/%.l $(outY)
    lex -o $@ $<

# Files made by Yacc
$(outY): $(srcDir)/%.c : $(srcDir)/%.y
    yacc -v -d -Wcounterexamples --file-prefix="$(srcDir)/y" $^

# Debug executables (outdated)
$(targets:%=%.db): $(objDebug)
    $(cc) -o $@ $^ $(ldFlagsDebug)

# Debug objects (outdated)
$(objDebug): $(debugDir)/%.do : $(srcDir)/%.c
    $(cc) $(cFlagsDebug) $^ -o $@

# Automated testing
$(tests): $(binDir)/%_test : $(testDir)/%_test.c $(filter-out $(mains), $(obj))
    $(cc) -o $@ $^ $(ldFlags) 
    $@

clean: 
    rm -rf $(objDir)/*.o $(debugDir)/*.do $(targets) $(tests) $(cleanY) $(outL)
```

Comment: You don't have to use $^ in the rule. Consider $<

Comment: @stark That works in this case, but I think the solution with filtering below is more general ; in case I do need multiple files from `$<` but also need to exclude some

Comment: "More general" is only useful when it's needed.  Almost every compiler for any language which is single-file-based and uses `-o` to specify an output file, only wants to have one input file on the command line.  In situations like that it will be an error to ever provide more than one prerequisite to the compiler in the recipe, and `$<` should be used, not `filter-out`.  If you have a more obscure language or compiler that can accept multiple source files and generate a single output file (or generate multiple output files) you might want to use `filter-out`.

Comment: Oops, or what Chris said... I didn't refresh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when *compiling* source files (as opposed to linking), you want to specify a *single* source file that compiles to a *single* object file.  This is precisely what `$<` is for so you just want a rule like:

```
$(objDir)/%.o: $(srcDir)/%.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

whihc will give you a separate compile command for each source.  If you try to compile multiple source files with a single invokation of the compiler, you run into trouble because you can't then use `-o` to specify the output, so you end up with all the .o files in the same directory as the .c files or in the current working directory (depending on how your C compiler works).

Answer (score 1):

Change `$^` to `$(filter-out %.h, $^)`. The `filter-out` function removes all words (sequences of non-whitespace characters) that match the pattern.

Comment: Seems a little hacky, although everything is in GNU Make ! I'll keep the question open for now, but this is a pretty good answer

Comment: I'd be interested to know what kind of solution you had in mind that was not "a little hacky".